# How to delegate Spring Integration Message Payload to Spring Batch Job?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-batch-integration

I have an **FTP Streaming Inbound Channel Adapter** from **Spring Integration** which produces message with payloads of type **InputStream**, letting files be fetched without writing to the local file system.

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = Constants.CHANNEL_INBOUND_FTP_ADAPTER, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = Constants.FIXED_POLLING_FROM_INBOUND_FTP_ADAPTER_DELAY))
public MessageSource<InputStream> ftpMessageSource() {
    FtpStreamingMessageSource ftpStreamingMessageSource = new FtpStreamingMessageSource(ftpRemoteFileTemplate());
    ftpStreamingMessageSource.setRemoteDirectory(ftpConnectionParameters.getRootDir());
    ftpStreamingMessageSource.setFilter(chainFileListFilter());
    ftpStreamingMessageSource.setMaxFetchSize(Constants.INBOUND_ADAPTER_MAX_FETCH_SIZE);
    return ftpStreamingMessageSource;
}
```

After I transform with

```
@Bean
@org.springframework.integration.annotation.Transformer(inputChannel = Constants.CHANNEL_INBOUND_FTP_ADAPTER, outputChannel = Constants.CHANNEL_STREAMED_DATA)
public Transformer transformer() {
    return new StreamTransformer(Charset.defaultCharset().name());
}
```

Then handle data to check it works and maybe for custom inteceptors for future:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Constants.CHANNEL_STREAMED_DATA, outputChannel = "BATCH_ALARM_CHANNEL")
public Message<?> alarmHandler(Message<?> message) {
        System.out.println(Constants.CHANNEL_ALARM);
        System.out.println(message.getHeaders());
        return message;
}
```

After this according to **official Spring Batch Integration documentation** I have one more Transformer which let us transform to **JobLaunchRequest**

```
@Transformer
public JobLaunchRequest toRequest(Message<File> message) {
    JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    jobParametersBuilder.addDate("dummy", new Date());
    return new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
}
```

Here we have **Message** from last **BATCH_ALARM_CHANNEL** which needs in Spring Batch Jobs, but **JobParametersBuilder doesn't allow to put complex object only primitive types**. So how I can pass message payload for JobLaunching and do the rest of the work such as read, parse and save to DB?

Comment: You don't as you shouldn't do it like that. Instead you probably should make (or find) a ftp based `ItemReader` and simply pass the filename/location to Spring Batch to retrieve it. Passng around an `InputStream` won't work especially as `JobParameters` as how should that be written to a database?

Comment: I second what @M.Deinum said. Moving an input stream around is not a good idea, as things may get serialized in between. The file name/location is a better option as input to the batch job.

Comment: @M.Deinum then it makes no sense to use spring integration because I have already read file from Inbound Channel Adapter, I can create File using apache commons FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, file) at Integration Layer without saving to file system it is not a problem. Do you recommend to read it twice from InboudChannelAdapter and then in Batch Job read it again by filename/location? I though that here Integration as a Transport and Batch as processing engine for messages from that transport.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine sure, but that would be redundant network connection to retrieve the file, which I already have. Looks illogical. Where are the benefits of using spring batch integration ?

Comment: You use the message to kickoff a batch process, but you shouldn't pass the binary data. That data will be stored in the database, so passing an `InputStream` around is thus a bad idea as there is no way to store that in a database. So you need a file or read it from FTP through Spring Batch. So actually Spring Integration isn't the transport so much but rather the triggering mechanism for the Batch part.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'll take note of this, it seems that integration is indeed mounted to a remote source in the first place in order to become a trigger for launching batch processes, mount a couple of filters for files and get simple type meta information for the job. Thank you.